# rails - wrap HTML element around text of link_to() in ruby code without disabling all escaping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, xss

This is pretty basic but I'm not having any luck finding anything in the Rails documentation.  There is a view helper method (Ruby code, *not* HAML) that returns

```
link_to(user_controlled_text, destination, options)
```

and I need to wrap an HTML element (namely `<bdi>`) around the `user_controlled_text`.  If I do

```
link_to("<bdi>#{user_controlled_text}</bdi>", ...)
```

then my element is treated as part of the user-controlled text to be escaped.  Fair enough.  How do I tell Rails not to escape the `<bdi>` and `</bdi>` but still escape the `user_controlled_text`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`content_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag):

```
link_to(content_tag(:bdi, user_controlled_text), destination)

# or with a block
link_to(destination) do
  content_tag(:bdi, user_controlled_text)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `link_to("<bdi>#{h user_controlled_text}</bdi>".html_safe, ...)`.

If the `h` doesn't work, use `ERB::Util::h`.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with first two answers, You can use a block as well if your link target is hard to fit into the name parameter. I have used like below

```
<%= link_to(destination) do %>
    <bdi>
        <%= user_controlled_text %>
    </bdi>
<% end %>
```

But I know this is not a valid HTML e.g div use inside `a href` tag.

Here is the complete reference